# Add a drop down list of cities on admin orders pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, admin, orders

I would like to add drop down list of cities to new order page in woocommerce, I know way to add this functionality to checkout page, but here I want to add this functionality **to admin new order pages** in Woocommerce.

See example image for reference:
[image: See example image for reference]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following hooked function for admin new order *(where you will set your array of cities)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields' , 'admin_billing_city_select_field' );
function admin_billing_city_select_field( $fields ) {
    global $pagenow;
    
    // Only for new order creation
    if( $pagenow != 'post-new.php' ) return $fields;

    $fields['city'] = array(
        'label'   => __( 'City', 'woocommerce' ),
        'show'    => false,
        'class'   => 'js_field-city select short',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            ''              => __( 'Select a city&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Los Angeles'   => __( 'Los Angeles', 'woocommerce' ),
            'San Antonio'   => __( 'San Antonio', 'woocommerce' ),
        ),
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> If you want it to work also for admin **edit order pages**, you will remove the following line:
>
> ```
> if( $pagenow != 'post-new.php' ) return $fields;
> ```

[image]